# C++17 Fold Expression not Compiling

Tags: c++, c++17

first time posting so sorry if I have poor format. I encountered fold expressions for the first time the other day and am trying to get something up and running with them. However, all of my attempts have failed to compile. I've boiled it down to the following:

```
//test.cpp

template<typename... types>
auto adder(types&... args){
    return (args+...);
}

int main(){return 0;}
```

And I compiled it with

```
g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp
```

And it produces the following errors:

```
testCode.cpp: In function 'auto adder(types& ...)':
testCode.cpp:5:15: error: expected primary-expression before '...' token
  return (args+...);
               ^
testCode.cpp:5:15: error: expected ')' before '...' token
testCode.cpp:5:18: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
  return (args+...);
                  ^
testCode.cpp:5:18: note:         'args'
```

From everything I've seen this should be working, so if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

I'm working with xenial linux (on a crouton on chrome OS) and a fresh install of g++.

Comment: Which version of g++ are you using? This should work with current versions of all major compilers ([try for yourself here](https://godbolt.org/z/YcN-t_)). In the case of g++, it seems to work starting with version 6.1, which is already pretty old (latest version is 8.2). I guess you must be using a really ancient version…

Comment: I think that you edited this code sample. I was trying it out for myself and it broke until I fixed it. And now your code sample works just fine. What did you do?

Comment: Certainly works with GCC 8.1.0. crouron on a chromebook is perhaps not the best C++ development environment - much as I like chromebooks.

Comment: Hello all, as Kenzel suspected, this was a versioning issue with the g++ compiler. Not sure what my computer was default installing, but a newer version does fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::literals;

template<typename... T>
auto add(const T&... args) {
        return (args + ...);
}

int main() {
        std::cout << add(1,2,3,4) << "\n";
        std::cout << add("a"s, "b"s, "c"s) << "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver I suspect the asker edited his question because I copied it, and saw the error. And now I don't. So ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

as Kenzel suspected in the comments, this was a versioning issue with the g++ compiler. Not sure what my computer was installing by default, but going to a linux repository and manually installing a newer version of g++ fixed the issue. Thanks for the help everyone!